# Pass index from loop to click function added to each element in the loop?

Tags: javascript

Im looping through an array of list elements on my page and attaching click event to each one. When I log the clicked element I can see its working.

```
    var loop = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < optionsList.length; i++) {
            optionsList[i].addEventListener("click", optionClicked);
        }
    }

    var optionClicked = function() {
        console.log(this)
    }
```

Is there a way I can pass the index from the loop to the optionClicked function? I want to do something like this:

```
    var optionClicked = function() {
        console.log("You clicked number: " i)
    }
```

UPDATE Apologies to those who already answered, the code above is a simplified example. The solutions arn't working. Here is my actual code. I think the use of `this` is throwing the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

```
var optionsListener = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < optionsDomList.length; i++) {
        optionsDomList[i].addEventListener('click', optionClicked(i));
    }
}

var optionClicked = function(i) {
    if (currentQuestionAnswered === false) {
        this.className += "option-highlight";
        currentQuestionAnswered = true;
    }
    var correctAnswerNo = allQuestions[step].correctAnswer;
    console.log(this + i)
}
```

Comment: you can use a closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set index value to current option element

```js
function loop () {
    for (var i = 0; i < optionsList.length; i++) {
        optionsList[i].index = i;
        optionsList[i].addEventListener('click', optionClicked);
    }
}

function optionClicked(event) {
    console.log('You clicked number:', event.target.index);
}

// Example usage
var optionsList = document.querySelectorAll('li');
loop();
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Option item 1</li>
    <li>Option item 2</li>
    <li>Option item 3</li>
    <li>Option item 4</li>
    <li>Option item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It also works with console.log(this.index); and I dont need to pass the event to the optionClicked function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with a closure:

```
    ...addEventListener('click', optionClicked(i));

var optionClicked = function(i) {
  return function () {
    console.log('You have clicked: ' + i);
  };
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I simplified my code example for the sake of clarity but your solution doesn't work. Ive updated my question with my actual code.